Clarification on Self-Adjointness and Inverse Properties of a Specific Linear Operator.
I am seeking clarification on the self-adjointness and properties of the inverse of a particular linear operator.
Consider the linear operator $A= - \phi_{xx} + \phi_{xxxx}$ associated to the linear part of the Boussinesq equation:
\begin{align}
\phi_{tt} - \phi_{xx} + \phi_{xxxx} + (\phi^2)_{xx} = 0,
\end{align}
for all $ (x,t)\in (0,L) \times (0,T)$.
The domain of $A$ is given by
\begin{align}
D(A)=\{ \phi \in H^{4}(0,L): \phi(0)=\phi(L)=\phi_{x}(0)=\phi_{x}(L)=0 \} \subset L^{2}(0,L).
\end{align}
My question is as follows: If $A$ is self-adjoint and closed, and if its inverse exists, is the inverse also self-adjoint, compact, and bounded in $L^2(0,L)$.
I have already proven that $A$ is symmetric, that is:
\begin{align}
\langle A \phi, \psi \rangle_{L^2(0,L)} = \langle \phi, A \psi \rangle_{L^2(0,L)}, \ \forall \phi, \psi \in D(A).
\end{align}
This implies $D(A) \subset D(A^*)$.
To address my question, I have attempted to apply spectral theory to ensure the existence of the inverse by proving that 0 is not an eigenvalue of A, i.e., using the fact that $0 \in \rho(A)$ ($\rho(A)$ is the set of regular points of A)  if and only if there exists $C>0$ such that
\begin{align}
\langle A\phi, \phi \rangle_{L^2(0,L)} \geq C \|\phi\|_{L^2(0,L)},
\end{align}
but this is contingent on $A$ being self-adjoint.
Any insights or guidance on whether the inverse of $A$, if it exists, would be self-adjoint, compact, and bounded would be greatly appreciated.
